# Python thread breaks down silently when run in the background

Tags: python-3.x, django, multithreading

In django I am using thread to read xlsx file in the background but after sometimes it breaks down silently without giving any errors. Is there any way to start an independent thread not causing random failure?

```
thread_obj = threading.Thread(
                target=bulk_xlsx_obj.copy_bulk_xlsx
            )
thread_obj.start()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could set the thread as Daemon to avoid silent failure as follows:

```
thread_obj = threading.Thread(
                target=bulk_xlsx_obj.copy_bulk_xlsx
            )
thread_obj.setDaemon(True)
thread_obj.start()
```